# Cannot get .js mimetype to be recognized on local server even with extensions_map edited

Tags: javascript, python, server, mime-types

I'm trying to import a functions.js file into an html page generated with python (running on a local CGI server) but I keep getting the following message regardless of how I edit the extensions_map in my Server.py script.

```
The script from “http://localhost/functions.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

I tried putting many things in the functions.js file and calling them but it doesn't work.

Server.py

```
import http.server

port = 80
address = ("",port)
server = http.server.HTTPServer
handler = http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
handler.extensions_map=({
    '.manifest': 'text/cache-manifest',
    '.html': 'text/html',
    '.png': 'image/png',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
    '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.js': 'text/javascript',
    '': 'application/octet-stream', # Default
    })
handler.cgi_directories = ["/"]
httpd = server(address, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

html file:

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates\Stylesheet.css">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Script In Motion (Prototype)</title>
        <script src="functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

functions.js file

```
function logtest(){
    console.log("test");
}
```

I tried with extensions_map.update, same result. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was something stypid... I moved the file into a subfolder and it worked